# How to test that catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();} invoked

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I need to reach 95% test coverage (my task). I have problems with following class

```
    public class Context {

    public static <T> T getObject(Class<T> clazz) {
        Object bean = null;

        try {
            bean = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (T) bean;
    }

    private Context() {
    }
}
```

to reach 95% I need to check that `e.printStackTrace();` invoked when Exception thrown.
I tried different ways but none of them work. I will appreciate any support.

Comment: Check that null is returned. But, honestly, you don't want to catch that exception: just propagate the exception to callers.

Comment: How does you current test cases look like ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to check if e.printStackTrace(); is invoked. Just make sure the exception is thrown in your test case when clazz.newInstance() is called.

Comment: I agree with @matrixguy. You don't need to unit test the Java API; this should be done by the implementation team (Oracle, etc). [printStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) is part of `java.lang` package

Answer (score 1):

To verify that `printStackTrace` is called, the easiest way I can think of is a spy/mock `Exception` object.

Using mockito, you could pass in a mock `Class` which throws a spy `Exception` when `newInstance` is called.

```java
Class<?> mockClass = mock(Class.class);
Exception e = Mockito.spy(new Exception());
Mockito.doThrow(e).when(mockClass).newInstance();

context.getObject(mockClass);

Mockito.verify(e).printStackTrace();
```

You could also do something with powermock and `whenNew` if you know where the `Exception` is going to be thrown (so that you can `@PrepareForTest` that class).

```java
Exception e = Mockito.spy(new Exception());
PowerMockito.whenNew(Exception.class).thenReturn(e);

context.getObject(SomeService.class);

Mockito.verify(e).printStackTrace();
```

Note: I have not compiled and tested either of the above (and consistently get the `Mockito` and `PowerMockito` class names wrong in various ways).

---

If you're dead-set on doing this *without* a library you could do something like:

1. Create a custom `Exception` type, which explicitly sets some flag when that method is called:
2. Create a custom `class` which throws the above `Exception` when the no-arg constructor is called.
3. Pass the `.class` of this custom class into your method, and verify that the flag has been set.

Something like:

```java
class MyException extends Exception {
    public static boolean printStackTraceCalled = false;

    @Override
    public void printStackTrace() {
        MyException.printStackTraceCalled = true;
        super.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class MyClass {
    MyClass() {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}

@Test
void testThing() {
    context.getObject(MyClass.class);

    Assertions.assertTrue(MyException.printStackTraceCalled);
}
```

---

That said, that's just *how* you would do this...  I'm not saying this is a good idea.  That's a bad way to handle `Exception`s and targeting a specific % code-coverage is more often than not meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue. I refactored code a little bit:

```java
 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Context.class.getName());

    public <T> T getObject(Class<T> clazz) {
        T bean = null;

        try {
            bean = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, e, () -> "Exception occurred during Context usage whilst created " + clazz.getName());
        }
        return bean;
    }
```

and here it is the test:

```java
    @Test
    void getObject_ShouldThrowException() throws Exception {
        Exception mockedException = mock(InstantiationException.class);
        Logger mockedLogger = mock(Logger.class);

        class Dummy {

            public Dummy() throws Exception {
                throw mockedException;
            }
        }

        try {
            Dummy dummy = context.getObject(Dummy.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            verify(mockedLogger, times(1)).log(Level.INFO, anyString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
    public void `testUploadDocumentProtocolException`() throws `IOException` {
        when(

    openKMRepo.template(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(con);
        when(con.getOutputStream()).thenThrow(new ProtocolException());
        String result = openKMService.uploadDocument(file, "test/path", "123");

    

assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).